# How to override Django widget functions (Froala Editor)?

Tags: python, django, widget, froala, django-widget

I was wondering how I can override the functions `render` and `trigger_froala` in Django. Can I create my own widget which overrides the two functions?

```
from django.forms import widgets, Media
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.conf import settings
import json
from . import PLUGINS, PLUGINS_WITH_CSS, THIRD_PARTY, THIRD_PARTY_WITH_CSS

try:
    from django.urls import NoReverseMatch, reverse
except ImportError:
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, NoReverseMatch


class FroalaEditor(widgets.Textarea):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.options = kwargs.pop('options', {})
        self.plugins = kwargs.pop('plugins', getattr(settings, 'FROALA_EDITOR_PLUGINS', PLUGINS))
        self.third_party = kwargs.pop('third_party', getattr(settings, 'FROALA_EDITOR_THIRD_PARTY', THIRD_PARTY))
        self.theme = kwargs.pop('theme', getattr(settings, 'FROALA_EDITOR_THEME', None))
        self.include_jquery = kwargs.pop('include_jquery', getattr(settings, 'FROALA_INCLUDE_JQUERY', True))
        self.image_upload = kwargs.pop('image_upload', True)
        self.file_upload = kwargs.pop('file_upload', True)
        self.language = (getattr(settings, 'FROALA_EDITOR_OPTIONS', {})).get('language', '')
        super(FroalaEditor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        html = super(FroalaEditor, self).render(name, value, attrs)
        el_id = self.build_attrs(attrs).get('id')
        html += self.trigger_froala(el_id, self.get_options())
        return mark_safe(html)

    def trigger_froala(self, el_id, options):

        str = """
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#%s').froalaEditor(%s)
            });
        </script>""" % (el_id, options)
        return str
```

Comment: What's the code you're showing us? Where do you want to override? Django is just python, you can always subclass classes and override methods...

Comment: This is the FroalaEditor class that contains the two function that I would like to override.

Comment: So what's the problem? I suppose you know how to subclass and override methods in python... If not, learn python.

Comment: Thanks for this useless advice!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You're not saying what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from froala_editor.widgets import FroalaEditor

class CustomFroalaEditor(FroalaEditor):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomFroalaEditor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        html = super(FroalaEditor, self).render(name, value, attrs)
        return mark_safe(html)
```